# Unable to add product to cart: ajax loader image not found

Tags: magento2

I am unable to add product to cart my site link: bit.ly/2MtOjTn

By using inspect element I am getting following error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

[image]

I have deployed static content 
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

and I can see ajax loader in `pub/static` folder as well

I have cleared all cache including `var/cache` and browser cache but I am still getting same error and unable to add a product to a cart

Answer (score 0):

make sure the css

> Milople_Personalizedcool/view/frontend/web/css/colorpicker.css

does not start with some comments or have errors in css. try to ckeck it with css lint tool

Comment: checked and added this file, it was missing however still it didnt solve the problem products not adding in the cart

Comment: any log message?

Comment: no logs or error